# Execute view before controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Just started learning rails. I'm building my first e-shop.

I have my page `products/index` which list my products. This is the view (in Slim) :

```
- @products.each do |product|
 br 
 .ul class='list-group'
  li class="list-group-item row"
  .textlist class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-9"
    .element_products
      h4 <b>Category :</b>  #{product.category}
    .element_products
      h4 <b>Description :</b> #{product.content}
    .element_products
      h4 <b>Price :</b> #{product.price} euros
  button class='btn btn-primary btn-right' class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3" 
    p <b>Add to Cart</b>
    = link_to 'Add', shopping_cart_path(:product_id => product.id), :method => 'POST'
    i class="fa fa-cart-plus"
```

This code uses [this gem for the shopping cart](https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart). I'm trying to get a list of products in products/index, with a button to add the items to the cart.

The important part here is that I'm doing a #each on my Product table (line #1).
I have a controller for products, as follow :

```
  class ProductsController < ApplicationController
     def index
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        @products = Product.all
        @product = Product.new
      end
     [...]
  end
```

And this is my controller for the shopping cart :

```
class ShoppingCartsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :extract_shopping_cart

 def create
    @product_cart = Product.find(@product_id)
    @shopping_cart.add(@product_cart, @product_cart.price)
    redirect_to shopping_cart_path
 end

 def show
 end

  private
  def extract_shopping_cart
     shopping_cart_id = session[:shopping_cart_id]
     @shopping_cart = session[:shopping_cart_id] ?     
     ShoppingCart.find(shopping_cart_id) : ShoppingCart.create
     session[:shopping_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id
   end
 end
```

**The problem :**

In my view I use `.each` to show all products from the Product table.
To create a new product, I need to define `@product_cart` (the product that I want to add to my cart) in the controller `ShoppingCartsController`, line#5.

For now I defined it like this :

```
        @product_cart = Product.find(@product_id)
```

`@product_id` should increase every time my `.each` loop in the view is executed, so I can get `Product.find(1)`, then `Product.find(2)`, then `Product.find(3)`...
But I can't do that with the `@products.each` loop because this one is used in the view to display all the products. And the view is executed AFTER the controllers.

Is there any way to increment `@product_id` with the `.each` loop in my views, THEN get `@product_id` used by the controller in `Products#create` ?

Comment: you need to create a new product? or product_cart?

Comment: can you make your question clearer, I can't understand what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the product Id to the create method of the cart through this link.

```
 = link_to 'Add', shopping_cart_path(:product_id => product.id), :method => 'POST'
i class="fa fa-cart-plus"
```

**Here you are sending `product_id`., Which you can use in controller through params.**

Your controller should be changed to,

```js
class ShoppingCartsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :extract_shopping_cart

 def create
    @product_cart = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @shopping_cart.add(@product_cart, @product_cart.price)
    redirect_to shopping_cart_path
 end

 def show
 end

  private
  def extract_shopping_cart
     shopping_cart_id = session[:shopping_cart_id]
     @shopping_cart = session[:shopping_cart_id] ?     
     ShoppingCart.find(shopping_cart_id) : ShoppingCart.create
     session[:shopping_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id
   end
 end
```

If you take **`params[:product_id]`** you will get the id's of the product selected to add to cart, with which you can create.

Comment: Hi ! I can't access the code right now, I'll test and validate your answer in 30 min =)

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you very much !!